# Problemas con C# en Visual Studio para Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macos

¿Cómo puedo hacer un proyecto de C# en  Visual Studio para Mac, cambiando `.NET Code` por `.NET Framework`?

Ya descargue e instale Mono. 
¿Qué hago después?

Comment: Seria mejor que usaras visual studio code [https://code.visualstudio.com/](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: windows forms? wpf? ASP.net? ASP.net Core? ¿Qué error te aparece? Bienvenido a SOes :D

Comment: Aún ningún error, solo que no se como empezar el proyecto usando lo que viene siendo .NET Framework en mi programa de C#, ya que la empresa a la que empezare a trabajar me pide utilizar eso, y yo como utilizo Mac descargue Visual Studio pero viene incorporado con .NET Code

Comment: en ese caso, virtualiza un Windows, Net Core != Net Standard. Te será más fácil a menos que donde trabajes utilicen .Net Core :D

Comment: Pero ellos mismos me dijeron que podría utilizar lo que es Mono

Comment: revisa la documentación oficial :D http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/

Comment: Si amigo, gracias!